# Fire a particular event on enter key form ASPX page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my content page my code is like that

```
<asp:Panel runat="Server">

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Open Me" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

</asp:Panel>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

On pressing `enter` key it's calling both the events first text changed then button click?

Any simple trick to call only text changed event: I don't want both event get fired.

Comment: The button click event is firing because pressing enter invokes the button client-side.  I suppose you *could* set the text box to auto post-back, but that's probably going to result in a terrible user experience.  The button is what's invoking the post-back in the first place.  If you don't want to use it, add some other means of invoking the post-back and use that instead.  Or maybe have some server-side conditional which gets set in `Page_Load` or in the text changed event which indicates that the text has changed and conditionally perform logic in the click event based on that.

Comment: Thanks david ...any code snippet or javascript to solve that issue

Comment: thanks frenchie for editing ..

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood a few things... Not only can I not provide a ready-made solution for your client-side since you haven't shown anything *about* your client-side code, but also what sort of JavaScript solution are you looking for?  Of the various options I suggested (and any others you might be considering), what are you looking to do?  I'm happy to help answer questions, but this isn't a code-fixing service.